# Delete pieces of Session on browser close

Tags: python, django, session, cookies

I am going to be storing a significant amount of information inside Django's session cookie.  I want this data to persist for the entire time the user is on the website. When he leaves, the data should be deleted, but the session MUST persist. I do not want to user to need to log in every time he returns to the website.

I found ways to purge the entire session cookie every time a user leaves the website, but ideally I would like to only delete select pieces of the cookie which I explicitly set.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I think you need to make your question a bit clearer. What do you want to persist, what do you not want to persist? Isn't  the `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` satisfactory for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing things a bit.

The only thing stored inside "Django's session cookie" is an ID. That ID refers to the data which is stored inside the session backend: this is usually a database table, but could be a file or cache location depending on your Django configuration.

Now the only time that data is updated is when it is modified by Django. You can't expire data automatically, except by either the cookie itself expiring (in which case the entire set of data persists in the session store, but is no longer associated with the client) or by running a process on the server that modifies sessions programmatically.

There's no way of telling from the server end when a user leaves a website or closes his browser. So the only way of managing this would be to run a cron job on your server that gets sessions that were last modified (say) two hours ago, and iterate through them deleting the data you want to remove.

Comment: alright. That's a valid answer, so I need some help then. I have a photo application where the user can view a gallery of photos.  By clicking a button, he can request a new set of random photos from the server. I need to store all viewed photos on the server to prevent the user from seeing repeats. These are stored in the session. If the user logs in a second time, I want him to be able to see previously viewed photos, but I also want to preserve the session so he does not need to sign in again. Is there an alternative place that I can store these photos for a particular user? Thank you!

Comment: This should probably be a new question. The trick is understanding what you mean by "logs in a second time". How will you determine that? How will you distinguish between them keeping a tab in their browser open in your site for an afternoon, vs them closing and reopening? One way might be to just store a last_accessed_time in the session alongside the list of viewed photos: on the next access, if the timestamp is too old, delete it from the session, otherwise use/update it.